# 3 tables linq join plus foreach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, foreach

Three tables:

**GeoData**: 
ID

**Address**: 
ID, GeoDataID, UserID

**Products**: 
ID, UserID

There's a one to one relation between GeoData.ID and Address.GeoDataID and a one to many between Address.UserID and Products.UserID

I have an Array of GeoData ID as input and I want to get all related Products.

If I only had one GeoData ID I would try something like:

```
int geoDataID = 3456;
        using (var context = new BaseContext())
        {
            from p in context.Products
            join a in context.Addresses on p.UserID equals a.UserID
            join g in context.GeoData on a.GeoDataID equals g.ID
            where g.ID == geoDataID
            select new { p };
        }
```

but as I have an Array (int[] geoData) as input I can't manage to put it together.

Comment: If `geoDataID` is `int[]`, then `where geoDataID.contains(g.ID)`

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand your comment: is it supposed to be a workaround to get the expected result?

Comment: Its not clear what your aasking but if `geoDataID` is say `int[] geoDataID = new int[]{ 1, 2, 3 }` then replace `where g.ID == geoDataID` with the code in my first comment

Comment: Although I do not understand why you need the join to `GeoData` when you could just use the `GeoDataID` of `Address`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
using (var context = new BaseContext())
        {
         var results =   from p in context.Products
            join a in context.Addresses on p.UserID equals a.UserID
            where geoData.Contains(a.geoDataID)
            select p;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as intendend. Also 

"where geoDataID.Any(item => item == a.GeoDataID)".
Is there any reason to prefer 'Contains' to 'Any' method?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is use the [Contains()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains(v=vs.110).aspx) method on the collection of geo data ids to filter the records you want.

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsByGeoData(IEnumerable<int> geoDataIds)
{
    var products = context.GeoData
        .Where(gd => geoDataIds.Contains(gd.Id))
        .Join(context.Addresses,
            gd => gd.Id,
            a => a.GeoDataId,
            (gd, a) => a)
        .Join(context.Products,
            a => a.UserId,
            p => p.UserId,
            (a, p) => p);
    return products;

}
```

Comment: I have an array of int as input. Your suggestion requires a Ienumerable<int> (or maybe Ienumerable<int?>). I have no idea how to cast my actual input to ienumerable required.

Comment: @Luke, an array of int (`int[]`) **is** an `IEnumerable<int>`.